# KendoUI year and week picker

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker

I was wondering if is there any posibility to make a kendoDatePicker where you can select only the year ?
Also for weeks in a year is possible to make a kendoDatePicker ?

Thanks.

Comment: In looking at the documentation for the kendo date picker, it doesn't appear to be possible: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/datepicker. There is the `depth` property that you can set, but it's unclear exactly what that property changes, so you might try playing around with that to see the results.

Answer (score 16):

set both start and depth to "decade" and format to "yyyy"

Declaratively:

```
<input id="yearpicker" data-role="datepicker" data-start="decade" data-depth="decade" data-format="yyyy" />
```

Programably:

```
 $("#yearpicker").kendoDatePicker({
                    start: "decade",                          
                    depth: "decade",                           
                    format: "yyyy"
                });
```

For weeks, so far I don't see it's supported. Use user voice.